# Detecting time lapse in UILongPressGestureRecognizer in Swift 3

Tags: time, swift3, intervals, seconds

I'm trying to get the seconds a user longPress a button, I have tried this and no luck. It used to work perfectly in Swift 2. now it give me a long decimal number.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: myButton!

var longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLong(_:)))

 myButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)


 func tapLong(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var touchTime = 0.0

    if sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

            touchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

            touchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - touchTime

            print(touchTime)


        }
    }
```

Comment: I tought that it was obvious that myButton had an outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a `UIButton`, I would recommend using `@IBAction`s and connect `buttonDown(_:)` to the *TouchDown* event, and connect `buttonUp(_:)` to *TouchUpInside* and *TouchUpOutside*.

```
var startTime = Date()

@IBAction func buttonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    startTime = Date()
}

@IBAction func buttonUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let endTime = Date()
    let elapsed = endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
    print(elapsed)
}
```

---

To connect the actions, click on the button in the Storyboard and bring up the *Connections Inspector* and then drag from the desired events to the `@IBAction`s.

[image: Connection an action in the Storyboard]

Comment: appreciate the help, I do have it connected, its just that it doesn't give me seconds, it gives big decimal numbers... I'm not sure in what format it is.

Comment: The value is a `Double` and specifies seconds.  So `1.50000120202030` would be just slightly longer than 1 and 1/2 seconds.  If you want an `Int`, then use `Int(elapsed)` to throw away the fractional seconds.